# Spectrum of the Laplace operator

Tags: matlab, eigenvalues, poisson

I am studying the discretization of Poisson's equation in $1D$. In Matlab I created different discretization matrices (Laplace operator) according to different sizes of the mesh:

```
% Parameters
N = [40, 80, 160, 1280]; % Dimension 1-D grid

% Laplace operators
L1 = -1/((1/N(1))^2) * full( ( spdiags(repmat([1,-2,1], N(1)-1, 1), -1:1, N(1)-1, N(1)-1) ) );
L2 = -1/((1/N(2))^2) * full( ( spdiags(repmat([1,-2,1], N(2)-1, 1), -1:1, N(2)-1, N(2)-1) ) );
L3 = -1/((1/N(3))^2) * full( ( spdiags(repmat([1,-2,1], N(3)-1, 1), -1:1, N(3)-1, N(3)-1) ) );
L4 = -1/((1/N(4))^2) * full( ( spdiags(repmat([1,-2,1], N(4)-1, 1), -1:1, N(4)-1, N(4)-1) ) );
```

I then plotted the eigenvalues of the matrices using

```
[V1, D1] = eig(L1);
plot(diag(D1) / norm(diag(D1),2), '--');
```

What I see is that as I increase $N$ (so the step size goes to zero), the difference between the biggest and the smallest eigenvalues decreases. Therefore the condition number is getting better. Is there anything else I can see from such a plot?

Comment: I tried running your code snippet. You did not define D1.

Comment: The condition number is the ratio of largest to smallest eigenvalue. As $N$ increases, the condition number becomes *larger* not smaller.

Comment: @BillGreene From my plots, I see that if $N$ increases the ratio is getting smaller.

Comment: @LorenzoFabbri The ratio between maximum and minimum eigenvalues are definitely getting larger. Try `max(diag(D1))/min(diag(D1))`. Why are you dividing by the norm of D1 in your plot?  `max(diag(D1) / norm(diag(D1),2) )` is getting smaller, but that's a meaningless quantity.